# JavaHelp, creating the DefaultSearchEngine gives error

Tags: java, netbeans, javahelp

Am using JavaHelp with a java desktop application. 
 The application is developed with the NetBeans 7 IDE and pc with Windows 7 OS.
  I have the topic files created as HTML files , helpset and the navigation files.
  The search engine is specified in the helpset file as shown below:

```
 <view>
        <name>Search</name>
        <label>Search</label>
        <type>javax.help.SearchView</type>
        <data engine="com.sun.java.help.search.DefaultSearchEngine">JavaHelpSearch</data>
    </view>
```

But anytime I try to use the search system in the javahelp view , I get the following error.

```
Exception while creating engine named com.sun.java.help.search.DefaultSearchEngine for view: javax.help.SearchView@fd25f2b
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at javax.help.search.MergingSearchEngine.makeEngine(MergingSearchEngine.java:166)
    at javax.help.search.MergingSearchEngine.<init>(MergingSearchEngine.java:60)
    at javax.help.JHelpSearchNavigator.getSearchEngine(JHelpSearchNavigator.java:110)
    at javax.help.plaf.basic.BasicSearchNavigatorUI$SearchActionListener.actionPerformed(BasicSearchNavigatorUI.java:119)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1664)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:899)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:727)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidParameterException
    at com.sun.java.help.search.DefaultSearchEngine.<init>(DefaultSearchEngine.java:86)
```

Please can anyone explain the problem to me and how do I fix it.